# virtualenv installation SSLError: The read operation timed out

Tags: python, apache2, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to deploy python flask application using apache2 and mod-wsgi.
I am following [this](http://fosshelp.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-deploy-flask-application-with.html) link.

While installing mog-wsgi using the command `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi` ,I see these lines at the end

```
apache2_invoke: Enable module wsgi
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
apache2_reload: Your configuration is broken. Not restarting Apache 2
```

Is this a smooth installation?
Also, in step 1 of the link when I tried to create a virtual environment using the command

```
sudo virtualenv venv
```

This gives me error `sudo: virtualenv: command not found`

So, I tried to install virtualenv using `sudo pip install virtualenv`, I am getting this huge error in red(exception).

```
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
Downloading virtualenv-15.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8MB): 733kB downloaded
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1198, in prepare_files
do_download,
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1376, in unpack_url
self.session,
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 572, in unpack_http_url
download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 433, in _download_url
for chunk in resp_read(4096):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 421, in resp_read
chunk_size, decode_content=False):
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 225, in stream
data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 174, in read
data = self._fp.read(amt)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 573, in read
s = self.fp.read(amt)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
data = self._sock.recv(left)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 341, in recv
return self.read(buflen)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 260, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len)
SSLError: The read operation timed out

Storing debug log for failure in /home/myname/.pip/pip.log
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: No, when a command says "The Apache error log may have more information." you should read the Apache error log and not consider this a normal situation.

Comment: Where can I find apache error log ? When I did 'locate error_log' it showed me all these:  /usr/share/cups/doc-root/help/ref-error_log.html
/var/log/cups/error_log
/var/log/cups/error_log.1.gz
/var/log/cups/error_log.2.gz
/var/log/cups/error_log.3.gz
/var/log/cups/error_log.4.gz
/var/log/cups/error_log.5.gz
/var/log/cups/error_log.6.gz
/var/log/cups/error_log.7.gz

Answer (score 1):

Please use `apt-get install virtualenv` or `apt-get install python-virtualenv` (depending on your OS version) instead of polluting the system with packages installed by `sudo pip install`.

Comment: Isn't it `apt-get install python-virtualenv`?

Comment: @cricket_007 not since  1.11.6-1.

Comment: 'sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv' worked fine. Thanks guys.